# How to display the origin of an SQL query in the rails server console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In development mode, I would like to be able to see in the console where an SQL query was fired.

What is currently showing up in my console (dumb example query)

```
User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 65 LIMIT 1
```

What I would like to see

```
application_controller.rb:68
User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 65 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the line of code that triggers a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911371/how-to-get-the-line-of-code-that-triggers-a-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout https://github.com/RISCfuture/sql_origin for a gem that provides that.

Answer (score 1):

For future Googlers: The gem [active_record_query_trace](https://github.com/brunofacca/active-record-query-trace) can also do that and more.

Answer (score 1):

As of Rails 6+ (and maybe earlier), there is no need for an extra gem, the feature is now built in Rails.  Just set

```rb
ActiveRecord.verbose_query_logs = true
```

See [Rails Guides: Debugging Rails Applications: Verbose Query Logs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#verbose-query-logs).

You can also set it in the app configuration.

```
config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true
```

It's even enabled by default in Rails 7+.  See [Rails Guides: Configuring Rails Applications](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-active-record-verbose-query-logs).