# How to find the method name, class name and line number which triggered the query in rails 2.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I need to trace the line number a method name, class name and line number which triggered the query in rails 2.x I have found the following solution but it is not compatable with rails 2.x.

[How to get the line of code that triggers a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911371/how-to-get-the-line-of-code-that-triggers-a-query)

can any one please let me know is there any solution for this.

Even can any one plese provide information how to override default logger in rails to display caller method name and line number before every logger statement in rails 2.x

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175655/how-to-find-where-a-method-is-defined-at-runtime

Comment: Thank you the information is good there but not useful to me